# How do I get a rope arrow and a combat knife in the Soviet Installation episode?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

In *Rise of the Tomb Raider* (PC), there is a mission to get all the flags, but when I get near that, I get the message that the flag rope can only be cut with a combat knife.

[image: screenshot]

Also, there are some caves that are secured by wooden blocks wrapped in rope. When I go near that, it says that it requires a rope arrow.

[image: screenshot]

**How do I get a rope arrow and a combat knife in the Soviet Installation episode?**

Comment: This seems like two separate questions.

Comment: Both collectibles belong to the same episode that's why. Also, I got the rope arrow it is there in Gulag prison. On Lara's way out of prison, she gets it automatically.